# ¿Existe una API pública para consultar los estados y ciudades de México?

Tags: api

Conoces alguna alternativa, preferiblemente en POST. Estoy intentando realizar un  con dicha información.

Comment: No estoy seguro que tu pregunta se adapte a las normas del sitio. Lamentablemente no conozco una API que haga lo que pides. Pero !pudieses crear una! ¿No te parece? Saludos.

Comment: La situación es el mantenimiento de los datos actualizados. Estar actualizando dicha información no es viable.

Comment: Una búsqueda me dio como resultado esto: [Datos abiertos de México](https://datos.gob.mx/desarrolladores). Prueba allí. Y sin ánimo de ofender: ¡órale wey! Saludos

Comment: Puedes consultar el servicio meteorológico y desde allí extraes la información que necesitas [Condiciones atmosféricas](https://api.datos.gob.mx/v1/condiciones-atmosfericas). Es una idea. Tal vez se adapte a lo que necesitas. Saludos

Comment: Puede que esto sea lo que busca: https://api.copomex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No existe ninguna, yo hace tiempo me vi con un problema similar, lo que hice fue ir a la pagina del servicio postal mexicano y descargue la información y la metí a una tabla de base de datos para consultar y consumir. dicha pagina la puedes encontrara [Aqui](https://www.correosdemexico.gob.mx/SSLServicios/ConsultaCP/CodigoPostal_Exportar.aspx)

Comment: No es verdad. Aqui hay una API pública [Distribución territorial - México](https://datos.gob.mx/busca/dataset/distribucion-territorial). Es cuestión de buscar con ahínco. Saludos

Comment: eso no es un web service amigo, saludos.

Comment: Tienes razón y pido disculpas, sin embargo, se puede consultar la API del servicio meteorológico. [Condiciones atmosféricas](https://api.datos.gob.mx/v1/condiciones-atmosfericas) y desde allí obtienes la información que se necesite. Saludos